# Adding, Selecting and Deleting file names to a swiftUI list - MacOS

Tags: macos, swiftui, swiftui-list

I am trying to make an example project for adding, selecting and deleting file names to a swiftUI list. This is for MacOS as there are quit a few examples for IOS and there are a number of differences. I have managed to cobble together a partial working example from other sources, as shown, but there are quite a few pieces still missing. The current example will allow multiple items dragged from the finder to be added to the list, and then moved around but is missing the following:

Selecting items when added from finder via drag and drop
Selection of single/multiple items via mouse click
Filter out items based on some criteria before they are added
Deleting items via selecting then press delete

Nice to have:
Saving and restoring items as a bookmark

In addition, the current example can only add new items if there is already a dummy item in the array. Starting with an empty array prevents any insertions.

Any help with any of these would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var items : [Item] = (0..<1).map { Item(title: "Item #\($0)") }
    @State var selection = Int?.none

    var body: some View {
        List(selection: $selection){
            ForEach(items) { item in
                Text(item.title).frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            }.onDelete(perform: onDelete)
             .onMove(perform: onMove)
             .onInsert(of: [String(kUTTypeFileURL)], perform: onInsert)
        }
    }

    private func onDelete(offsets: IndexSet) {
        items.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }

    private func onMove(source: IndexSet, destination: Int) {
        items.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
    }

    private func onInsert(at offset: Int, itemProvider: [NSItemProvider]) {
       for provider in itemProvider {
            provider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: (kUTTypeFileURL as String), options: nil) {item, error in
                guard let data = item as? Data, let url = URL(dataRepresentation: data, relativeTo: nil) else { return }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.items.insert(Item(title: url.path), at: offset)
                   // let bookMarkData = try url.bookmarkData(options: .securityScopeAllowOnlyReadAccess, includingResourceValuesForKeys: nil, relativeTo: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Selecting items when added is pretty simple, you just have to insert a line of code into the onInsert after `self.items.insert(Item(title: url.path), at: offset)`, and remove it from the `dispatchQueue`. And add `self.selection = offset`.